# angular2-token calls return error status 0

Tags: angular, token, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I have Rails API app (with *devise_token_auth*) and Angular 4 (with *Angular2-token*) on Express server. If I run both locally, front end calls like `.validateToken()` and `.signIn()` returns `200` or `401` as expected. Though, now when I deployed both of them only status `0` returned and it looks to me like Angular2-token does not even produce any valid call.

My first impression that the cause in CORS on the back end,
which I implemented exactly like in docs: [devise_token_auth/cors](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#cors) or CORS on the front end and I added:

```
var cors = require('cors');
..
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors())
```

Unfortunately, it does not solve the problem.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved, here is what I did for those who encounter the same:

Actual problem was back end CORS. Current version has a lot of issues: https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors/issues
so,

1) I updated ***config.ru*** with:

```
use Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*',
      :headers => :any,
      :expose  => ['access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', 'client', 'content-type', 'cache-control'],
      :methods => [:get, :post, :options, :delete, :put]
  end
end
```

2) ***application.rb*** with:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
```

3) downgraded version via ***Gemfile***:

```
gem 'rack-cors', '0.4.1'
```